# search and replace issue infinite loop

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I'm not sure what causes the issue. My goal is pretty simple - I'd like to replace some text "abc.XXXX" with an incremental number so that it is transferred to "abc.0001", "abc.0002", "abc.0003" and so on. What happens is, that for some documents the script keeps running forever without replacing anything (at least not visibly) nor giving errors.

Here's my current code

```
With ActiveDocument.Content
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .text = ABC_123.XXXX
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        End With

        While .Find.Found = True
            count = count + 1
            lastReqNr = lastReqNr + 1
            .text = ABC_123. & Right(String(4, "0") & lastReqNr, 4)
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        Wend
    End With
```

For some documents this code works perfectly fine but some documents are causing issues. The variables are correctly filled in every case. Could the reason be that I'm working with modification tracking a lot?

Comment: Is there a way you can provide an example of a situation where it runs into the infinite loop? Also, what exactly does `S_FIND` equal?

Comment: Hey, of course. `S_FIND` equals e.g. "ABC_123.XXXX" and the infinite loop seems to appear in case the text is something like: `ABC_123.XXXX \n (former: ABC_003.004)`. I thought that an infinte loop shouldn't happen as the replacement overwrites the current value with ABC_123.0001 which doesn't match ABC_123.XXXX any more

Comment: I tried to figure out more in detail when the loop happens: it occurs whenever a paragraph is right behind the text to replace. Then word replaces `ABC_123.XXXX` with `ABC_123.0001ABC_123.0002ABC_123.0003...` and so on. Anyone an idea why the paragraph / line break leads to this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Didn't mention that track changes is active in the documents. If the search text was deleted by someone it will be revised. The macro replaces the text which (when track changes is active) will create another revision with the text which has to be replaced.

Simple but not perfect solution is to change the forward value to

```
Forward = False
```